# How do I fix the error "The specified module could not be found" when loading import statsmodels?

Tags: python, terminal

Statsmodels is installed in my computer and I am trying to run some files from the terminal through python3

When I try to run a .py file with import statsmodels.api as sm I get an error

[image]

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

did you do pip install statsmodels
or pip3 install statsmodels

it may have installed it to the wrong python version if you did not specify pip3

Comment: When I do that it says requirement already met.

Comment: I think that you should create a virtual environment and then do your pip installs in there. That way there won't be any conflicts with your system wide modules.